# The purpose of stdafx.h (And: Why doesn't this work?)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a project that has a vendor-provided API. I've made a class that uses that API in my project and I've included the vendors header file in my `stdafx.h` file. Things would not compile.

I then put the `#include` directly into my class' header file and now things compile (And yes, my class includes `stdafx.h` so that isn't the reason.

Do any of you have any guesses as to why it wouldn't compile the first time around? This isn't a project-stopper by far but I'd prefer if I could keep all vendor API files in stdafx.h where they belong.

EDIT: Problem solved, I'd created a cyclic dependency by forgetting to #ifndef a header file and then including them in the wrong order. I feel like an idiot.

Comment: 1) have you tried to re-create precompiled headers after adding there your libs?
2) not all dependencies may be met... add your own functionality to the last lines of stdafx, if it uses some default libs. That is just a suggestion, so not posting it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdafx.h` is mainly used in the VS generated projects as the 'container' of headers to be precompiled.

When you added a new `#include` to `stdafx.h` it didn't get included because your project is probably configured to use precompiled headers, and when you add something to `stdafx.h` you need to regenerate the .pch file that contains the precompiled information.

One way to do that is to have a .cpp file in your project that does nothing but `#include "stdafx.h"`. Maybe call it `precompile.cpp". Then go to the project settings *for that one .cpp file* and change the following setting (for all configurations):

```
"C/C++ | Precompiled Headers | Precompiled Header" setting
```

and select `"Create /Yc"`.

That will set up the build so that when `precompile.cpp` needs to be built (because the `stdafx.h` header it includes has changed), it'll rebuild the .pch file that everything else uses.

Comment: @medivh: I had forgotten about `stdafx.cpp`. But, the process I described 'works on my machine' - I just tried it. I don't know why the project build process wouldn't have picked up your change automatically (but precompiled headers do have a reputation for being finicky/error prone). Try a full rebuild of your project (or a clean/build set of steps), or compile `stdafx.cpp` manually (right click and select compile) then build your project again.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Wait - I don't think I read the question right. May still be helpful, though.

Another name for `stdafx.h` is a 'Precompiled header'

There aren't really any 'vendor specifics' in `stdafx.h`, what it does is it precompiles headers so that the compiler doesn't have to re-compile them every time you build the project.

It's only really helpful if you have a huge project (or a small one that includes tonnes of headers).

I use visual studio 2010 as well, generally it's not worth the fuss - I just disable it (which would solve your class inclusion issue also - make your own header, stick the vendor's in there).

Comment: Every time I attempt to remove and disable `stdafx.h`, *Visual Studio* seeks revenge on me.  I end up letting it have its way.

Comment: @wallyk - I don't think I've **ever** used precompiled headers since I switched from vs2008. Just start the project without 'em, and it doesn't complain at all. @medivh - That might be an idea, as the only other thing I can think of is if the files are included in the wrong part of `stdafx.h`